# How to remove empty hash from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I remove empty hash's from an array?

```
[{}, {}, :one, :two]
```

.compact does not seem to work.

Comment: `[{}, {}, :one, :two] - [{}]` is another way that hasn't been mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I remove empty hash's from an array?

Using reject, to reject elements in an enumerable by checking if the element is a Hash and is empty (`{}`):

```
p [{}, {}, :one, :two, [], [], '', nil].reject { |e| e == {} }
# [:one, :two, [], [], "", nil]
```

Comment: +1 I was going to post recommending the use of `select`, until I saw your answer. I feel `reject` is much more readable than `select` with negative conditions in the block.

Comment: The best answer as it can handle whatever's thrown at it :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland That does appear more concise, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Delete empty hashes:

```
ar = [{}, {}, :one, :two]
ar.delete({})
p ar # => [:one, :two]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Array#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) unwanted elements:

```
ary = [{}, {}, :one, :two]
ary.reject! { |h| h.empty? }
ary
#=> [:one, :two]
```